# display database changes in html5 using rxjs accessing restservice

Tags: html, rest, rxjs

Working on a project where the entity gets updated frequently in the database and the ui which is html5 will be displayed using rxjs via rest service.

html5->rxjs->restservice->db

Can someone has experience similar or achieved this ?

My Controller looks like this

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

import {HomeService} from './home.services';
import {Index} from './index';


@Component({
    selector: 'home-app',
    providers: [HomeService],
    templateUrl: 'MktHome.html',
})
export class HomeComponent {
    private indexes: Observable<Index[]>;
    constructor(private _service: HomeService){
        _service.getIndexes().subscribe(
                res => this.indexes =  res,
                error => alert(" Error is : " + error),
                ()=> console.log("finished")
             );
        console.log(this.indexes);
    }

    generateArray(obj){
        return Object.keys(obj).map((key)=>{ return obj[key]});
    }   
}
```

Service

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {  
    private actionUrl: string;
    private headers: Headers;   
    private requestoptions;
    constructor(private _http: Http) {
        console.log('Task Service created.', this._http);
        this.actionUrl = "http://localhost:8080/index/home";
        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        this.headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
    }


    // Uses http.get() to load a single JSON file
    getIndexes(){

        this.requestoptions = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Get,
            url: this.actionUrl,
            headers: this.headers})     

        return this._http.request(new Request(this.requestoptions)).map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

Thanks
Rafi

Comment: my architecture
db - postgres
service layer - java rest service
ui - HTML5 using angular2

there would be separate service which updates db and postgres broadcast those changes.

Idea is application will be working in the reactive way without user intervention for reflecting the changes in UI.

Comment: Why don't you show us what you have tried that isn't working?

Comment: all i have done is called the rest service with angular2 http interface and rendering the value to UI. I dont know how to render the updated value. I dont want to go for ui refresh rather i prefer push mechanism from server

Comment: I have pasted the controller which gets the data from the service which fetches by calling the rest service.

Comment: So which part isn't working?